# Display All Posts If First Query Results In No Posts

Tags: wordpress, loops, filter

I am trying to let visitors filter the loop to show posts that have multiple tags. However when the page first loads, no checkboxes are selected, so no posts are shown until checkboxes are selected and submitted. I would like the loop to default to showing all posts, and then be filtered from there.

```
echo '<form name="filterby" action="" method="GET">
<div class="filters">
<h4>Plant Type</h4>
    <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="tree"/><span class="filter-title">Trees</span></div>
    <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="shrub"/><span class="filter-title">Shrubs</span></div>
    <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="large-forb"/><span class="filter-title">Large Forbs</span></div>
    <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="medium-forb"/><span class="filter-title">Medium Forbs</span></div>
    <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="small-forb"/><span class="filter-title">Small Forbs</span></div>
    <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="tall-forb"/><span class="filter-title">Tall Forbs</span></div>
    <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="climbing-forb"/><span class="filter-title">Climbing Forbs</span></div>
    <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="groundcover"/><span class="filter-title">Groundcover</span></div>
    <h4>Root Type</h4>
    <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="taproot"/><span class="filter-title">Deep Roots</span></div>
    <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="shallow-roots"/><span class="filter-title">Shallow Roots</span></div>
    <h4>Native?</h4>
    <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="native"/><span class="filter-title">Native</span></div>
    <h4>Sun Requirements</h4>
    <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="full-sun" /><span class="filter-title">Full Sun</span></div>
    <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="partial-shade"/><span class="filter-title">Partial Shade</span></div>
    <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="full-shade" /><span class="filter-title">Full Shade</span></div>
    <h4>Water Requirements</h4>
    <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="regular-watering"/><span class="filter-title">Regular Watering</span></div>
    <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="moderate-watering"/><span class="filter-title">Moderate Watering</span></div>
    <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="drought-tolerant"/><span class="filter-title">Drought Tolerant</span></div>
    <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="drought-resistant"/><span class="filter-title">Drought Resistant</span></div>
    <h4>Soil Requirements</h4>
    <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="fertile-soil"/><span class="filter-title">Fertile Soil</span></div>
    <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="sandy-soil"/><span class="filter-title">Sandy Soil</span></div>
    <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="acidic-soil"/><span class="filter-title">Acidic Soil</span></div>
    <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="neutral-soil"/><span class="filter-title">Neutral Soil</span></div>
    <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="alkaline-soil"/><span class="filter-title">Alkaline Soil</span></div>
    <h4>Guild Roles</h4>
    <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="nitrogen-fixing"/><span class="filter-title">Nitrogen Fixing</span></div>
    <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="mulch-maker"/><span class="filter-title">Mulch Maker</span></div>
    <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="beneficial-insect-attractor"/><span class="filter-title">Beneficial Insect Attractor</span></div>
    <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="pest-repellant"/><span class="filter-title">Pest Repellant</span></div>
    <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="nutrient-accumulator"/><span class="filter-title">Nutrient Accumulator</span></div>
    <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="weed-barrier"/><span class="filter-title">Weed Barrier</span></div>
    <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="wildlife-food"/><span class="filter-title">Wildlife Food</span></div>
</div>
<div class="submit-filters">
    <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
</div>
</form>';

//Display Selections
$selection = $_GET['filter'];
  if(empty($selection)) 
  {
    echo("You are not filtering the list");
  } 
  else 
  {
    $N = count($selection);

    echo("You are currently filtering for: ");
    for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
    {
      echo($selection[$i] . ", ");
    }
  }

$tags_for_query = "'" . implode('+', $selection) . "'";
echo($tags_for_query);
// The Query
$query1 = new WP_Query( array( 'tag' => $tags_for_query  , 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC','posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
// The Loop
if ( $query1->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query1->have_posts() ) {
        $query1->the_post();
        $plant_size = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Size', true );
        $sun_requirements = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Sun Requirements', true );
        $water_requirements = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Water Requirements', true );
        $soil_consistency = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Soil Consistency', true );
        $soil_ph = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Soil pH', true );
        $fertilizer = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Fertilizer', true );
        $self_fruitful = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Self-fruitful?', true );
        $pruning = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Pruning', true );
        $guild_roles = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Guild Roles', true );
        $edible_info = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Edible Information', true );
        $growing_info = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Growing Information', true );
        echo '<ul class="catalog">
                <li>
                    <details>
                        <summary>' . get_the_title() . '</summary>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <details>
                                    <summary>Size:</summary>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>' . $plant_size . '</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </details>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <details>
                                    <summary>Sun Requirements:</summary>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>' . $sun_requirements . '</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </details>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <details>
                                    <summary>Water Requirements:</summary>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>' . $water_requirements . '</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </details>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <details>
                                    <summary>Soil Consistency:</summary>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>' . $soil_consistency . '</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </details>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <details>
                                    <summary>Soil pH:</summary>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>' . $soil_ph . '</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </details>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <details>
                                    <summary>Fertilizer:</summary>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>' . $fertilizer . '</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </details>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <details>
                                    <summary>Self-fruitful?</summary>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>' . $self_fruitful . '</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </details>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <details>
                                    <summary>Pruning:</summary>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>' . $pruning . '</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </details>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <details>
                                    <summary>Guild Roles:</summary>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>' . $guild_roles . '</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </details>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <details>
                                    <summary>Edible Information:</summary>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>' . $edible_info . '</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </details>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <details>
                                    <summary>Growing Information:</summary>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>' . $growing_info . '</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </details>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </details>
                </li>
            </ul>';
    }
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
else {
    $query2 = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'post','orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC','posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
    // The Loop 2
    if ( $query2->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query2->have_posts() ) {
          $query2->the_post();
            echo "here i am";
    }
        /* Restore original Post Data */
        wp_reset_postdata();
}
    else {}
}
```

I currently have the code set up so that "if" there are no posts found in the first query, "else" it runs a new query to display all posts.

However I can't figure out how to make the second query/loop work.

Answer (score -2):

Your code is almost correct. But the issue is that you're checking if the $selection array is empty, and if it is, you're running a new WP_Query to get all posts and you're not properly displaying the posts in second query.

Second query should be:

```
if ( $query2->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query2->have_posts() ) {
        $query2->the_post();
        echo '<h2>' . get_the_title() . '</h2>';an example
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}2
```

or you can do with the one query also

Here is code

```
echo '<form name="filterby" action="" method="GET">
 // All your form fields
$selection = $_GET['filter'];
$tagIds = array();

// Get the ID of selection
if(!empty($selection)) {
    foreach($selection as $tag_slug) {
        $tag = get_term_by('slug', $tag_slug, 'post_tag');
        if($tag) $tagIds[] = $tag->term_id;
    }
}

$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'tag__in' => $tagIds,
    'orderby' => 'title', 
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1 
));

if ($query->have_posts()) {
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        // All your post data
    }
wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    echo 'No posts found';
}
```